# create a new column for each unique value in an existing column and how to apply a function to values of the new column

Tags: pandas, loops, iterator

i am trying to create a new column for each unique value in the cluster_ids column. also,in the new column the values should be 1 for the respective "cluster_id" it was created and remaining values should be 0.

I have limited experience with coding.  I am just a beginner. I tried to resolve this my creating a function which is:

[my sample dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5tBg.png)
[picture of new columns for each unique cluster_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gupob.png)

`def get_y_value(cluster_ids): if cluster_ids == 0: return 1 else: return 0`

as a next step, i created a for loop to iterate over the rows but the values for the new columns are same.  I think it is because for "get_y_value" function.

`for j in (df['cluster_ids'].unique()): col_name = 'Clid' +"_"+ str(iterator) df_xyz.loc[:, col_name] = df['cluster_ids'].apply(get_y_value)   iterator += 1`

I would appreciate it if someone could give some suggestions as to how I can change the value in the get_y_value function for each unique value.

Comment: [mre]: Please post your input data and a desired output, in addition to "Gupob", which seems to be your current unsatisfactory attempt. All as text: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy-paste e.g. the output of `print(df)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1

If I got your intent right and if using `scikit-learn` as a part of your dependencies, this works nicely:

```
import sklearn.preprocessing as skp
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"cluster_ids": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3]})

unique_clusters = df["cluster_ids"].sort_values().unique()

binarizer = skp.LabelBinarizer()
binarizer.fit(unique_clusters)

columns = [f"Clid_{i}" for i in unique_clusters]

print(pd.DataFrame(binarizer.transform(df["cluster_ids"]), columns=columns))
```

Result

```
   Clid_0  Clid_1  Clid_2  Clid_3  Clid_4
0       1       0       0       0       0
1       0       1       0       0       0
2       0       0       1       0       0
3       0       0       0       1       0
4       0       0       0       0       1
5       1       0       0       0       0
6       0       1       0       0       0
7       0       0       1       0       0
8       0       0       0       1       0
```

It uses LabelBinarizer to basically perform a one-hot encoding based on the unique `cluster_id`s. You pass the unique sorted clusters to the `LabelBinarizer` and then it assigns 1 for the cluster that was on the row and 0 for the others.

### Solution 2

You can also do it without any extra dependencies and much easier with `pd.get_dummies`

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(df["cluster_ids"]).astype(int)
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  0  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0  0
2  0  0  1  0  0
3  0  0  0  1  0
4  0  0  0  0  1
5  1  0  0  0  0
6  0  1  0  0  0
7  0  0  1  0  0
8  0  0  0  1  0
```

See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html for more info.